# SAS prompt multiple list

Tags: sas, prompt, enterprise-guide

I have two static list of customers  and i have created two different prompts from the list. When I include those prompts in the code I want SAS to ask me to select either one of them.

So basically it should show me both the static lists from those but allows me to select only from both the prompts.

**I don't know if this can be done using prompts but all I want to do is to select any one of the customer list from the two lists, it would be really appreciated if prompts cab be used**

I have tried all the ways but nothing is helping. Please request you to help me with this.

Comment: I'm confused about what you are asking for.  You have list (A) and list (B).  Should your prompt allow you choose all of EITHER (A) or (B)?  Should the prompt allow you to choose items from (A) AND (B)?  Should the prompt allow you to choose items from (A) OR (B)?

Comment: Is this an Enterprise Guide question?

Comment: @dompazz yes the prompt should allow me to use either  list (A) or the list (B).

Comment: @snorehouse yes, this is a SAS enterprise eguide question

Comment: Either and not both, right?  XOR?

Comment: @Joe, it's like the EG should show me both the list but I have to select any one from those two lists

Comment: Any reason you can't just have one list then, with both data sources combined together?

Comment: @Joe, I can have both the list together but the list of customer names are huge, around 100 in each of the, so thats why want to different lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do what you are looking for in the prompts (to my knowledge).

If you cannot have just one list, which is really what you have, then create the two lists and have a prompt for each, allowing you to select only 1.  In your code, then you have to decide if 2 are selected, which you should use.

You can alter this as needed, but something like this to decide what to use.

```
%global selectedVar;

%macro choose();
%if "&var1" = "" %then %do;
   %let selectedVar = &var2;
%end;
%else %do;
   %let selectedVar = &var1;
%end;
%mend;
```

Then in your code, use `&selectedVar`.